# Mysql - when user arrived at work

Tags: mysql

I'd like to get information when user arrived at work. I've a simple db with two tables.
Checkpoint table writes event when user crossing door in both direction.

```
mysql> describe checkpoint;
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(7)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| date      | datetime | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| direction | text     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id   | text     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
mysql> describe users;
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | text    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I need a query to get first event (typically this is "IN" event in "direction" field. Of course if user didn't spent night at the work and now he's going "OUT") for all users for specified range of dates and for specified range of times.
Currently I have a query which return me the first events for one day:

```
SELECT users.name, checkpoint.date
FROM checkpoint INNER JOIN users ON users.id = checkpoint.user_id
WHERE direction = 'in'
AND date BETWEEN '2014-07-03' AND '2014-07-04'
GROUP BY users.name ORDER BY checkpoint.date
+------+---------------------+
| name | date                |
+------+---------------------+
| yko  | 2014-07-03 07:55:22 |
| set  | 2014-07-03 08:11:27 |
| ydo  | 2014-07-03 08:19:27 |
| vpu  | 2014-07-03 08:23:30 |
| ata  | 2014-07-03 08:44:34 |
| sak  | 2014-07-03 08:45:20 |
| sse  | 2014-07-03 08:45:31 |
| msn  | 2014-07-03 08:50:02 |
| ssh  | 2014-07-03 08:57:39 |
| emo  | 2014-07-03 09:00:30 |
| vrz  | 2014-07-03 09:03:16 |
| ade  | 2014-07-03 09:04:10 |
| abu  | 2014-07-03 09:13:53 |
| ozu  | 2014-07-03 09:18:02 |
| sma  | 2014-07-03 09:19:26 |
| mis  | 2014-07-03 09:24:57 |
| alt  | 2014-07-03 09:25:09 |
| epr  | 2014-07-03 09:26:00 |
| ogo  | 2014-07-03 09:26:05 |
| sgo  | 2014-07-03 09:28:21 |
| ppo  | 2014-07-03 09:29:48 |
| mts  | 2014-07-03 09:33:26 |
| ami  | 2014-07-03 10:05:18 |
| emy  | 2014-07-03 10:32:34 |
| ato  | 2014-07-03 11:05:33 |
+------+---------------------+
```

For at least above output I expect to get this row

> | mts  | 2014-07-03 09:33:26 |

with such a condition

> TIME(date) BETWEEN '09:29:59' AND '09:44:59'

But ideally I need to combine two conditions: **date BETWEEN** and **TIME(date) BETWEEN**.
I believe here should be some kind of JOIN or SUBQUERY syntax, but I couldn't achieve result.

This query return right result but only for one date due GROUP BY:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM \
    -> (SELECT users.name, checkpoint.date  \
    -> FROM checkpoint INNER JOIN users ON users.id = checkpoint.user_id  \
    -> WHERE direction = 'in' \
    -> AND date BETWEEN '2014-07-03' AND '2014-07-04' \
    -> GROUP BY users.name ORDER BY checkpoint.date) as n \
    -> WHERE TIME(n.date) BETWEEN '09:29:59' AND '09:44:59';
+------+---------------------+
| name | date                |
+------+---------------------+
| mts  | 2014-07-03 09:33:26 |
+------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
mysql> SELECT users.name, checkpoint.date  \
    -> FROM checkpoint INNER JOIN users ON users.id = checkpoint.user_id \
    -> WHERE direction = 'in' \
    -> AND user_id = 19
    -> AND date BETWEEN '2014-07-03' AND '2014-07-04' \
    -> LIMIT 0, 10;
+------+---------------------+
| name | date                |
+------+---------------------+
| mts  | 2014-07-03 09:33:26 |
| mts  | 2014-07-03 12:47:15 |
+------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

But when I increase date range without GROUP BY I got wrong result, because at least **abu** already has first registration at **| abu  | 2014-07-03 09:13:53 |** and his output here **| abu  | 2014-07-03 09:30:40** | unwanted:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM \
    -> (SELECT users.name, checkpoint.date  \
    -> FROM checkpoint INNER JOIN users ON users.id = checkpoint.user_id  \
    -> WHERE direction = 'in' \
    -> AND date BETWEEN '2014-07-02' AND '2014-07-04') as n \
    -> WHERE TIME(n.date) BETWEEN '09:29:59' AND '09:44:59';
+------+---------------------+
| name | date                |
+------+---------------------+
| epr  | 2014-07-02 09:30:08 |
| ato  | 2014-07-02 09:30:48 |
| alt  | 2014-07-02 09:32:04 |
| ppo  | 2014-07-02 09:33:12 |
| abu  | 2014-07-03 09:30:40 |
| sak  | 2014-07-03 09:30:52 |
| mts  | 2014-07-03 09:33:26 |
+------+---------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT users.name, checkpoint.date  \
    -> FROM checkpoint INNER JOIN users ON users.id = checkpoint.user_id \
    -> WHERE direction = 'in' \
    -> AND user_id = 2
    -> AND date BETWEEN '2014-07-02' AND '2014-07-04' \
    -> LIMIT 0, 10;
+------+---------------------+
| name | date                |
+------+---------------------+
| abu  | 2014-07-03 09:13:53 |
| abu  | 2014-07-03 09:30:40 |
| abu  | 2014-07-03 11:08:46 |
| abu  | 2014-07-03 11:08:49 |
| abu  | 2014-07-03 12:04:49 |
| abu  | 2014-07-03 12:43:58 |
| abu  | 2014-07-03 13:07:58 |
| abu  | 2014-07-03 13:32:16 |
| abu  | 2014-07-03 13:50:44 |
| abu  | 2014-07-03 14:25:57 |
+------+---------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: is the timeframe on the same day as the dayframe? i.e. 2014-07-04 to 2014-07-05 and 08:00 to 10:00 on every day?

Comment: I've just edited my post above, hope this help to understand.

Answer (score 0):

try this one for the timeframe from 09:29:59 to 09:44:59 every day

```
SELECT users.name, checkpoint.date
FROM checkpoint INNER JOIN users ON users.id = checkpoint.user_id
WHERE direction = 'in'
AND CAST(date as DATE) BETWEEN '2014-07-03' AND '2014-07-04'
AND CAST(date as TIME) BETWEEN '09:29:59' AND '09:44:59'
GROUP BY users.name ORDER BY checkpoint.date
```

Oh, if you Group By the user, you won't be able to display multiple days.

if you want just select between times on different days you can use:

```
SELECT users.name, checkpoint.date
FROM checkpoint INNER JOIN users ON users.id = checkpoint.user_id
WHERE direction = 'in'
AND date BETWEEN '2014-07-03 09:29:59' AND '2014-07-03 09:44:59'
AND date BETWEEN '2014-07-03 19:29:59' AND '2014-07-03 19:44:59'
GROUP BY users.name ORDER BY checkpoint.date
```